# Why does "ab".match(/ab/) return ["ab","ab"]?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does the following code:

> "ab".match(/(ab)/);

return this:

> ["ab", "ab"]

Though `ab` appears once in the string `ab` , why does `ab` appear twice in the array?

Comment: Have you looked at any [doco for `.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)? Try it without the parentheses and see what you get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first element contains the entire matching string, while the next elements contain the group matches. Consider:

```
> "somestring44".match(/[a-z]([a-z]*)/)
["somestring", "omestring"]
```

Comment: And the doc is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value